# localstack container using dynamodb and DATA_DIR, not persisting tables after docker commit

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I am trying to create an image based on a localstack container running dynamodb, where a set of tables exist when the container starts. My understanding was that I could use the env variable DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data, then create the tables and commit the container, creating a new image with the persisted tables. When I run the new image the tables do not exist. Is this the correct way to persist tables in a localstack/dynamodb instance, or is there a better way to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create a Dockerfile that copies an exist shared-local-instance.db to the data directory.

```
FROM localstack/localstack 

COPY shared-local-instance.db /tmp/localstack/data/dynamodb/shared-local-instance.db
```